# Strange and unidentified readings in SpeedFan (Almico)

Tags: temperature, speedfan

[image]

**Why is the AUX temperature so high** in this [Almico Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) reading?

Comment: this varies from chipset to chipset, and may not be reading correctly. speedfan does its best to identify the sensors and read them correctly, but with so much variance between chipsets and implementations on different motherboards, its the best they can do. Try using other tools like CoreTemp, CPUZ, Speccy, etc to see if you are actually experiencing that heat on an identifiable sensor, and if not, just ignore the reading.

Comment: yes, now that I can see your image, that is definitely a bad reading, not an actual temp. This weekend, I was monitoring my mobo (with the Asus Thermal Radar util that came with my mobo) while playing a game, because it really heats up the VCORE1 and VCCSA components. While I was watching, the Motherboard sensor started reading -134C. rebooted and everything started working right. sensors are sensitive things and can do really odd stuff sometimes. Neither is your GPU fan running at greater than 10k revolutions per second. very few fans can do that in a minute.

Comment: Then temperatures and revolutions per second okay?

Comment: I think @FrankThomas means you will not have to worry about those strange readings, but confirming with another hardware sensor tool like AIDA64 [http://www.aida64.com/downloads] would help.

Comment: @FrankThomas, maybe you should write it down as an answer, so the original poster can accept your question.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez, That is exactly what I'm thinking. thank you for clarifying. Op, just ignore the abherent readings, since they are too far off to be likely. Were I you however, I'd double confirm everything with other utilities, just for piece of mind.

Comment: Note the strange RPM readings for GPU Fan, too